# Are there any good resources (preferably books) about techniques used for entity extraction?

Tags: natural-language-processing, resource-request, books, named-entity-recognition

Given some natural language sentences like

> I would like to talk to Mr. Smith

I would like to extract entities, like the person "Smith".

I know that frameworks, which are capable of doing so (f. e. RASA or spaCy), exist, but I would like to dive deeper and understand the theory behind all this.

At university, I learned a few of the basic models like CRF's or SVM's used for this task, but I wonder if there are any good resources (preferably books) about this topic.